# How can i make a water pump circuit

Tags: sensor, circuit-design

I have a plant that I want to automatically water. I have a plan to buy a small fountain pump which plugs into a wall. I am also going to build a small soil [moisture sensor](http://gardenbot.org/howTo/soilMoisture/) to see if the soil is dry. I want to find a simple way to let power go through the wall outlet to the pump once the sensor circuit is broken from the soil dryness. I am only 12 years old and I don't have a soldering iron so please help me find a way to make a circuit to water my plant. Thanks!

Comment: Where will the water get pumped from? A large pond or something?

Comment: no a bucket or something like that

Comment: Can't you just get/make a drip feeder? Basically a tube full of water with a small hole in the bottom to allows water to drip through into the soil. No mechanical or electronic bits required.

Comment: No its too big of a plant to drip feed

Comment: Do [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Wicks-to-Water-Plants) and be done with it.

Comment: I am going to suggest that you use a programmable board, an arduino or something, to control a 24 VAC irrigation valve. The 24 VAC will come from a transformer. No pump. The pump creates a lot of problems (pumps will be damaged if run dry). Just make sure the bucket or something is high enough for water to flow to the plant through a bit of hose by gravity. Use a relay to switch the 24 VAC to the valve.

Comment: Consider changing your question title to be an actual question.

Comment: thank you guys! any ideas on the arduino code for it?

Comment: If you are not good at coding, just use a comparator to turn on your valve (or pump).

Comment: Submersible aquarium pumps are quite a good idea, but again should not be allowed to run dry.

Answer (score 2):

For something that a 12 year old budding engineer can work with, how about using an off-the-shelf wireless remote outlet [like this $10 one from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087EIDRS) and hack the remote control instead of dealing with the AC power directly.

Try it out on your fountain pump. Then you can see if you can make an electronic circuit (transistors and opamps) or computer circuit (Arduino, Rasperry Pi, etc) to read the moisture sensor and control the remote control.

You can either electrically simulate the button presses or you can use one or two servos to physically press the ON and OFF buttons on the remote.

I hope this points you in a good and useful direction for your design. -Vince

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Sparkfun soil moisture sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13322).  They have a tutorial that goes over automatically watering a plant based on the sensor reading.  They also sell a [water pump that operates on 12v DC](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10455).